# Directive making $scope.$watch fire twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have the following `$watch` statement:

```
$scope.$watch('text', function () {
  $scope.obj = new Obj(text);
  $scope.obj.next();
});
```

`$scope.text` is the `ng-model` of the following input:

```
<input id="text" type="text" ng-model="text" name="text"/>
```

This works fine.  However, when I abstract out the above input box along with some other HTML into a directive, the `$scope.$watch` chunk begins firing twice upon changes in `$scope.text`.  Here is the directive I am abstracting out into:

```
myApp.directive('objDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: myApp.$scope,
      controller: 'objController',
      template: '<form name="textform" id="textform">' +
                '<input id="text" type="text" ng-model="text"' +
                'name="text"/></form>',
      replace: true
    };
});
```

**In short:  `$watch` properly fires once when input box changes, but when input box is placed into a directive, it fires twice.  Why is this?**

Comment: The first is possibly the watch initialization (i.e. initial watch execution) and the latter when ngModel binds empty string? (just guessing)

Comment: Although it fires twice for *every change in the input box after that*.  So when it is initialized it fires twice.  Then when I type "a" into the input box it fires twice.  And so on.

Comment: This line `scope: myApp.$scope,` is pretty strange and suspicious.

Comment: Agreed.  What should I be putting here?  I don't have a strong understanding of directive scope attributes.  I tried `scope: { text: '=' }`, which did nothing.

Comment: In fact, when I edit the scope line to `scope: {}`, the `$watch` begins properly only firing once, although the scope is isolated then so this solution isn't very useful.

Comment: You are actually doing bad practice binding directly to a scope variable. If you want to do that, just don't create any directive scope. And drop `transclude` as well as it is useless in your case.

Comment: Oh I know.  This is for an assignment however, and I need to follow this structure.  And I left out code that uses the `transclude`.

Comment: Transclusion will automatically create child scope for the contents, so you need to bind to some object and not just scope property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

The problem was simply that I was defining both the controller in the HTML and in the directive.

Answer (score 1):

The $watch does not fire twice in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/K6VmYNLfq7jPtWJGq1IV?p=preview)

JS

```
app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("test", [ function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        template: '<form name="textform" id="textform">' +
                '<input id="text" type="text" ng-model="text"' +
                'name="text"/></form>',
        replace: true,
        scope: app.$scope,
        controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
          $scope.$watch("text", function(newValue) {
            if (angular.isDefined(newValue)) {
              console.log(newValue);
            }
          });
        }]
    };
}]);
```

Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <test></test>
  </body>

</html>
```